# How to replace the Data Array in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I have a DataTables table that is initially filled by a JSON Array (directly written to HTML with ASP.NET). Now I want to refresh this data with Ajax but the data simply won't be added. I want to use my own method, not DataTables' internal Ajax method. (Using DataTables 1.10.0).

```
$.getJSON("?ajax=1", null, function(json, status, xhr) {
    var table = $("#" + proTableId).DataTable();

    oSettings = table.settings();
    //table.clear();
    table.rows().remove();

    var data = table.data();
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
    {
        data.push(json[i]);
    }
    table.draw();
});
```

The JSON result is correct but after this call the DataTable is always empty. How do I replace the Data inside the DataTables object and preferably keep sorting and filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding data to the data table, you have to access the property row of the data table object, and then call the add method. Finally, you update this table by calling the draw method.

As it can be seen on the [Data Table documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html). You would have to do this:

```
for(var i= 0; i < json.length; i++){
    table.row.add([
       json[i].firstProperty,
       json[i].secondProperty
    ]).draw();
}
```

Comment: this works, but I had to change it a little bit `table.row.add(json[i]);`